# Issue with creating virtual pages at GTM and sending it to GA

Tags: google-analytics, tags

Got a problem creating a funnel in GA with virtual pages. There is a landing with three events. 
- Button "Sign up" - after clicking - you go down to the next button
- Button "Participate" - after clicking - form opens, where you should fill you name, phone etc
- Button "Submit" - after clicking - form submits and that's it.

I created events on all of these steps and it works well in GA.
But also I need a funnel. There is no redirecting, so I tried to use virtual pages to track this clicks. But after all settings, nothing happens. Funnel doesn't work and it doesn't track any "visits" to virtual pages. 
I read many manuals and everywhere it seems easy and works well. But not in my case.

[ga settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhiGH.png)
[gtm settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwD1m.png)

Comment: could you please share and exact snippets of 'virtual pageviews'?

Comment: you mean gtm settings? attached

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot, you are using an Event tag. If you are trying to track them as virtual pageviews, use a pageview tag with page and title configured as fields under More Settings > Fields and fire the pageview tag via a click trigger